# Rounded corners and border for a SwiftUI List Section

Tags: swiftui

I want to create the following [design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vx0Z.png) in SwiftUI. I am currently using a list and creating a section that contains cells like so.

```
List {
    Section {
        ForEach(titles) { title in
            Cell(title: title)
        }
    }
}
```

When I apply a modifier like a border to the section it applies it to all the views contained in the Section. I want to have that border around the entire Section with a corner radius of 10. The closest I have got to creating the desired design is by not using a List but instead using a VStack and applying the following modifiers

```
VStack {
    ForEach(titles) { title in
        Cell(title: title)
    }
}
.overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
            .stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 2))
```

I discovered however that this is not a smart approach as the List uses reusable cells and in the case of VStack they do not. Is it possible to create the wanted design with a List in SwiftUI? I do not want to opt for the default list style provided by Apple

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: Code Preview]

Just Copy paste this code and customise it as per your needs, enjoy

```
import SwiftUI

struct CustomizeListView: View {

var titles = ["First Section" : ["Manage your workout", "View recorded workouts", "Weight tracker", "Mediation"], "Second Section" : ["Your workout", "Recorded workouts", "Tracker", "Mediations"]]


var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(titles.keys.sorted(by: <), id: \.self){ key in
            Section(key) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0){
                    ForEach(titles[key]!, id: \.self) { title in
                        HStack{
                            Text(title)
                            Spacer()
                            Image(systemName: "arrow.right")
                        }//: HSTACK
                        .padding(20)
                        Divider()
                    }//: LOOP
                }//: VSTACK
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .circular).stroke(Color(uiColor: .tertiaryLabel), lineWidth: 1)
                )
                .foregroundColor(Color(uiColor: .tertiaryLabel))
            }//: SECTION
        }//: LOOP
    }//: LIST
    .listStyle(InsetListStyle())
}
}

struct CustomizeListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    CustomizeListView()
}
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. Thank you!

Comment: I have noticed that the VStack acts as one whole row and the rows inside that VStack are not reused. Would there be any alternative that allows these rows to be reused by the list but still overlay the section with a rounded rectangle?

Comment: I have run the code and it is reusing cells, try adding more sections in dictionary like 8 to 10 sections then add onAppear on your cell's Text and and print the title of cell, you'll notice cell is reusing, also you can check amount of cells created in Debug Memory Graph to check that cell is reusing or not

Answer (score 0):

I assume you just need to change list style, like

```
List {
    Section {
        ForEach(titles) { title in
            Cell(title: title)
        }
    }
}
.listStyle(.insetGrouped)       // << here !!
```

Comment: This does round the list sections off with a corner radius but it seems that the corner radius value can not be changed and when I apply a border modifier to the Section it still applies the border to all the elements contained in the Section still

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out the hack:

```
ForEach(titles.keys.sorted(by: <), id: \.self){ key in
            Section(key) {
                VStack(
```

with **VStack** simply does not work: appearance seems fine BUT navigation is completely broken!

I have the same problem of a border for both a section ad its items.
I resolved writing a custom modifier applied to header, and another to single item cells but also a footer to nicely close the border

It seems a but hackish, but works.

Some pieces of code: (I miss original code from apple sample:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/displaying-data-in-lists

to reduce cluttering.)

a) make top shape and modifier:

```
fileprivate let RADIUS = CGFloat(20)
fileprivate let overCompensateUpAndDown = CGFloat(12)

struct TopRoundedBorder: Shape {
    let  adjustDown = CGFloat(10)
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY +  adjustDown))

        let leftPt = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY+RADIUS)
        path.addLine(to: leftPt)
        
        let leftCenter = CGPoint(x: rect.minX + RADIUS, y: rect.minY+RADIUS)

        path.addRelativeArc(center: leftCenter, radius: RADIUS,
                            startAngle: Angle(radians: 3.14),
                            delta:  Angle(radians: 1.57))
        
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX-RADIUS, y: rect.minY)) // we can skip, CoreGrtaphics will joit arcs.
        
        let rightCenter = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - RADIUS, y: rect.minY+RADIUS)

        path.addRelativeArc(center: rightCenter, radius: RADIUS,
                            startAngle: Angle(radians: 3.14 + 1.57),
                            delta:  Angle(radians: 1.57))
  
        // we should be already here, anyway:
        //let rightPt = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY+RADIUS)
        // go down at right:
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY + adjustDown))
        
        return path
    }
}
```

B) bottom modifier:

```
// here we needoverCompensateUpAndDown as we are NOT using Apple header.
struct BottomRoundedBorder: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        
        // start from topleft:
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY - overCompensateUpAndDown))

        let leftPt = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY-RADIUS)
        path.addLine(to: leftPt)
        
        
        let leftCenter = CGPoint(x: rect.minX + RADIUS, y: rect.maxY-RADIUS)

        path.addRelativeArc(center: leftCenter, radius: RADIUS,
                            startAngle: Angle(radians: 3.14),
                            delta:  Angle(radians: -1.58))
        
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX-RADIUS, y: rect.maxY)) // we can skip, CoreGrtaphics will joit arcs.
        
        let rightCenter = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - RADIUS, y: rect.maxY-RADIUS)

        path.addRelativeArc(center: rightCenter, radius: RADIUS,
                            startAngle: Angle(radians: 1.57),
                            delta:  Angle(radians: -1.57))
  
        // we should be already here, anyway:
        //let rightPt = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY-RADIUS)
        // go up at right:
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY - overCompensateUpAndDown))
        
        return path
    }
}
```

C) add border to cell, too:

```
struct BordersOnBothSides: Shape {
    let withSeparator: Bool
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        

        // start from topleft:
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY - overCompensateUpAndDown))

        let leftPt = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY + overCompensateUpAndDown)
        path.addLine(to: leftPt)
        
        // top rigth:
        let overCompensateRightArrow = CGFloat(18)
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX+overCompensateRightArrow, y: rect.minY - overCompensateUpAndDown))

        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX+overCompensateRightArrow, y: rect.maxY + overCompensateUpAndDown))
      
        return path
    }
}
```

D) other modifiers and glue code:

```
enum BorderMode {
    case up
    case down
}



private struct BordersOnBothSidesModifer: ViewModifier {
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .overlay(
                BordersOnBothSides(withSeparator: true)
                    .stroke(Color.primary, lineWidth: 1)
            )
    }
}


public extension View {
    func bordersOnBothSides(color: Color? = nil) -> some View {
        modifier(BordersOnBothSidesModifer(/*color: color*/))
    }
}
 


struct BorderedHeaderFooterView: View {
    let text: String
    let mode: BorderMode
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if mode == .up{
                TopRoundedBorder()
                    .stroke(Color.blue)
                Text(text)
            }else{
                BottomRoundedBorder()
                    .stroke(Color.green)
                Text(text)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

E) in list:

```
struct DepartmentList: View {
    let department: Department
    var body: some View {
        HeaderView(department: department)
        //Section(header: HeaderView(department: department)) { works also in this way ...
            ForEach(department.staff) { person in
                NavigationLink(destination: PersonDetailView(person: person)) {
                    PersonRowView(person: person)
                }
            }
        //}
        FooterView(txt: "notes for " + department.name)
    }
}



struct HeaderView: View {
    var department: Department
    var body: some View {
        //wqs: Text(department.name)
        BorderedHeaderFooterView(text: department.name, mode: .up)
            .frame(height: 80)
    }
}

struct FooterView: View {
    var txt: String
    var body: some View {
        BorderedHeaderFooterView(text: txt, mode: .down).frame(height: 80)
    }
}



struct StaffList: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(company.departments){  department in
                    DepartmentList(department: department)
                }
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .navigationTitle("Staff Directory")

            // Placeholder
            Text("No Selection")
                .font(.headline)
        }

    }
}
```

It's working, but I had to patch manually some coords (can break in future...)

so at the end I got: (I used fake colors to show)

[image]

God bless me.;(

A bit longer explanation but needed.
(feel free to contact to have full sample code, may be a GIST, I will do).